# Delete a SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, simplexml

I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002313/php-simplexml-delete-please-tell-me-why-the-first-variant-is-not-working)) an answer regarding the way to delete a node of a SimpleXMLElement object.

The problem is I can not really understand how is that happening.

I mean, that $image var is a ref, right? So, what and where it is that `$image[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement` presents an array-like interface on its child nodes via magic methods. This behavior is because of custom [`__unset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.unset) behavior that causes the SimpleXMLElement to act as though a "member" (child element) of its "array" (set of child elements) has been removed.

Comment: Is there a place where I can see this details of SimpleXMLElement implementation ?

Comment: I should have figured that there is something linked to __unset() while it is triggered when attempted to unset members that object doesn't have setted..

Comment: You can [read the C source code of `SimpleXMLElement`](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/simplexml) from PHP's github repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a print_r($image) right after the $image = $galleries->xpath(...

you'll see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Hansio
                )

        )

)
```